# JavaScript - I cannot get appendChild operation to work when using it in combination with parentNode.replaceChild

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a hamburger menu that is generated in JS with a replaceChild operation. If JS is disabled, there is a standard button in place of the Hamburger.

The JS hamburger is a pseudo-element with a 'click' function. I need to generate this element with a classList attached so I can style and control the hamburger animation.

Currently that createElement > classList.add > appendChild is not working. I am unsure why this part of my code is not generating the needed child element. However, I am able to generate the 'button' without an issue.

````
<nav>...
            <div class="hamburger-wrapper">
            <div hidden data-menu-button class="nav-toggle">Menu</div> <--// pseudo-element goes here
            <ul id="menu" data-menu>
              <li><a class="color-shift" href="/">Case Studies</a></li>
              <li><a class="color-shift" href="/">About Izzy</a></li>
            </ul>

...</nav>

(function menu() {
  const fakeButton = document.querySelector('[data-menu-button]');
  const menu = document.querySelector('[data-menu]');

  const toggleMenuButton = document.createElement('button');
  toggleMenuButton.textContent = fakeButton.textContent;
  toggleMenuButton.setAttribute('aria-expaned', false);
  toggleMenuButton.setAttribute('aria-controls', 'menu');
  toggleMenuButton.classList.add('nav-toggle');

  const toggleMenuHamburger = document.createElement('div');
  toggleMenuHamburger.classList.add('hamburger-menu');
  toggleMenuHamburger.appendChild(toggleMenuButton);

  fakeButton.parentNode.replaceChild(toggleMenuButton, fakeButton);

  toggleMenuButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let expanded = this.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true' || false;
    this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', !expanded);
    menu.hidden = !menu.hidden;
  });

  menu.hidden = true;
})();

(function hamburgerAnimation() {
  $('.hamburger-wrapper').on('click', function () {
    // console.log('click');
    $('.hamburger-menu').toggleClass('animate');
  });
})();```
````

Comment: _"'It doesn't work' isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_ (Source: [mcve])

Comment: Shouldn't you replace `fakeButton` with `toggleMenuHamburger`?

Comment: See my second comment

Comment: _"I will try and simplify the code..."_ - That's not necessary. My only concern with my first comment was the _"...is not working"_. Therefor I copy&pasted the relevant part of the help section which happens to be the one for a [mcve] - which your question already is.

Comment: @Andreas I will try and simplify the code so anyone can run it. As for clarification. The only problem with the code is that the pseudo-element is not being created or appended to the DOM. The button is getting generated, and all the attributes including ARIA are working for screen readers. Pressing the button toggles the menu so it's just the div for the pseudo-element 'hamburger' which is not being added to the document. I will create a stand-alone codepen tomorrow if I am still stuck.